# R- Comparing rows in matrix for certain conditions

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a history table (table: HT) containing purchase information in the following structure

**Supplierno**    **itemno**    **price**
ABC123                101              50
ABC124                105              55
BCD201                103              60
BCD211                103              60
EFG103                103              45

Then I get new data in the same format(table: NT) on a periodic basis. I want to determine cases in the new data feed, where vendors are supplying the same item at prices . I wanted to the equivalent of a 
SQL query that will do a

select NT.* from newtable where NNT.itemno=HT.itemno AND NT.price<>1.2*HT.price

I tried HT[HT[(HT.itemno==NT.itemno) & (HT.price!=NT.price)] but always get 0 results even though there are instances that should get picked up.

Somehow comparing columns in a row works well with this approach, but not same column across rows

I know I can run loops but my HT table is large(>1M) and understand thinking vectors will be more efficient.

Look forward for inputs and guidance

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table you can also try: (reusing @Wave's example)

```
library(data.table)
HT=data.table(supplier=c("ABC123","ABC124","BCD201"),itemno=101:103,price=c(50,55,60))
NT=data.table(supplier=c("ABC123","ABC124","BCD201"),itemno=101:103,price=c(50,55,65))
merge(HT,NT,by=c("itemno","supplier"))[price.x!=price.y]
```

Comment: thanks- as I asked @Wave, gain would this allow me to make the comparison through a function?

Comment: yes, you can use this for example `merge(HT,NT,by="itemno")[price.x!=price.y & stringdist(supplier.x,supplier.y)<2]`

Comment: ok- but if I had to match based on both stringdist<2 and item no, and then check for price variations(to limit checks for same vendor AND item), I wouldnt be able to use merge on equality. Can the 'by' clause handle this

Comment: that I'm not sure, also i added the supplier in the by clause in the answer, i miss copied it the first time

Answer (score 0):

To recreate you data:

```
HT=data.frame(supplier=c("ABC123","ABC124","BCD201"),itemno=101:103,price=c(50,55,60))

NT=data.frame(supplier=c("ABC123","ABC124","BCD201"),itemno=101:103,price=c(50,55,65))
```

To select from the new dataframe the cases where the price is changed:

```
NT[NT$itemno %in% HT$itemno & NT$price!=HT$price,]
```

Comment: thanks- a related case is where I need to have approx matches (a) like stringdist fn of vendorname comparisons<2 (2) price variation is between 80-125%. Is there a way the field comparisons can be functions?